# How to make my svg image circle which is currently square with bored radius

Tags: svg, vector, graphical-logo

How to make my SVG image circle which is currently square with a bored radius.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="1000pt" height="1000pt" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" version="1.1">
<defs>
<linearGradient id="linear0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="3.475598" y1="1.1821" x2="102.7784" y2="1.1821" gradientTransform="matrix(10.07021,0,0,10.07021,-35.000003,-11.90396)">
<stop offset="0" style="stop-color:rgb(49.803922%,0%,100%);stop-opacity:1;"/>
<stop offset="1" style="stop-color:rgb(88.235294%,0%,100%);stop-opacity:1;"/>
</linearGradient>
</defs>
<g id="surface1">
<path style=" stroke:none;fill-rule:nonzero;fill:url(#linear0);" d="M 783.335938 0 L 209.425781 0 C 55.613281 0 0 53.488281 0 213.285156 L 0 789.226562 C 0 944.03125 55.613281 1000 209.425781 1000 C 209.425781 1000 628.230469 1000 783.335938 1000 C 938.441406 1000 1000 944.03125 1000 789.226562 C 1000 634.421875 1000 213.285156 1000 213.285156 C 1000 53.488281 940.460938 0 783.335938 0 Z M 581.554688 288.144531 L 652 288.144531 L 425.09375 711.855469 L 343.601562 711.855469 M 671.117188 356.039062 L 671.210938 288.625 L 896.488281 466.210938 C 896.164062 487.175781 896.808594 511.339844 896.488281 532.304688 L 671.210938 709.894531 L 671.390625 641.867188 L 856.292969 499.550781 Z M 143.707031 499.550781 L 328.609375 641.867188 L 328.789062 709.894531 L 103.511719 532.304688 C 103.191406 511.339844 103.835938 487.175781 103.511719 466.210938 L 328.789062 288.625 L 328.882812 356.035156 Z M 143.707031 499.550781 "/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Edit it in an SVG editor such as Inkscape.

Comment: I have asked for changes to the SVG code. Not via using other tools

Comment: Use the tool to change the code then examine what it did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've changed the first part of the paths d attribute:

> M 783.335938 0 L 209.425781 0 C 55.613281 0 0 53.488281 0 213.285156 L 0 789.226562 C 0 944.03125 55.613281 1000 209.425781 1000 C 209.425781 1000 628.230469 1000 783.335938 1000 C 938.441406 1000 1000 944.03125 1000 789.226562 C 1000 634.421875 1000 213.285156 1000 213.285156 C 1000 53.488281 940.460938 0 783.335938 0 Z

with a circle like so:

> M0,500a500 500 0 0 0 1000 0a500 500 0 0 0-1000 0

The circle begins in the point x:0,y:500: **M0,500**

has a radius of 500 both on x and y: **a500 500**

and runs counter-clockwise: a500 500 0 0 **0** 1000 0

```css
svg{width:200px;}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" version="1.1">
<defs>
<linearGradient id="linear0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="3.475598" y1="1.1821" x2="102.7784" y2="1.1821" gradientTransform="matrix(10.07021,0,0,10.07021,-35.000003,-11.90396)">
<stop offset="0" style="stop-color:rgb(49.803922%,0%,100%);stop-opacity:1;"/>
<stop offset="1" style="stop-color:rgb(88.235294%,0%,100%);stop-opacity:1;"/>
</linearGradient>
</defs>
<g id="surface1">
  
  
<path id="kk" style=" stroke:none;fill-rule:nonzero;fill:url(#linear0);" d="M0,500a500 500 0 0 0 1000 0a500 500 0 0 0-1000 0
                                                                    
 M 581.554688 288.144531 L 652 288.144531 L 425.09375 711.855469 L 343.601562 711.855469 M 671.117188 356.039062 L 671.210938 288.625 L 896.488281 466.210938 C 896.164062 487.175781 896.808594 511.339844 896.488281 532.304688 L 671.210938 709.894531 L 671.390625 641.867188 L 856.292969 499.550781 Z M 143.707031 499.550781 L 328.609375 641.867188 L 328.789062 709.894531 L 103.511719 532.304688 C 103.191406 511.339844 103.835938 487.175781 103.511719 466.210938 L 328.789062 288.625 L 328.882812 356.035156 Z M 143.707031 499.550781 "/>
  
  
  
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to keep initial `<path>` and define a new variation ([`<symbol>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/symbol)) of it that uses [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) in order to hide corners...

Changes I made:

1. The initial SVG is no longer visible. It just holds defined variations of the icon. Variations are defined as `<symbol>` tags.
2. A variation refers to the origin `<symbol>`: `<use href="#icon"/>` with custom styles.
3. In your page you can refer (and show) icon variations:

   ```
   <svg class="icon">
     <use href="#icon"/>
   </svg>
   ```
4. I minified your icon `<path>` to make it more readable.

```css
.icon {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Icon Definition (invisible) -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="0" height="0">
  <symbol id="icon" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="linear0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="3.475598" y1="1.1821" x2="102.7784" y2="1.1821" gradientTransform="matrix(10.07021,0,0,10.07021,-35.000003,-11.90396)">
        <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:rgb(49.803922%,0%,100%);stop-opacity:1;"/>
        <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:rgb(88.235294%,0%,100%);stop-opacity:1;"/>
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <path style="stroke:none; fill-rule:nonzero; fill:url(#linear0); pointer-events: bounding-box;" d="M783 0 209 0C56 0 0 53 0 213L0 789C0 944 56 1000 209 1000C209 1000 628 1000 783 1000C938 1000 1000 944 1000 789C1000 634 1000 213 1000 213C1000 53 940 0 783 0ZM582 288 652 288 425 712 344 712 582 288M671 356 671 289 896 466C896 487 897 511 896 532L671 710 671 642 856 500ZM144 500 329 642 329 710 104 532C103 511 104 487 104 466L329 289 329 356ZM144 500"/>
  </symbol>

  <symbol id="iconCircle" style="clip-path: circle(50%);">
    <use href="#icon"/>
  </symbol>
</svg>

<!-- Icon Demo -->
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; flex-wrap: wrap; max-height: 170px;">
  <!-- Default icon -->
  <span>Default</span>
  <svg class="icon">
    <use href="#icon"/>
  </svg>

  <!-- ClipPath circle icon -->
  <span>clip-path: circle(50%)</span>
  <svg class="icon">
    <use href="#iconCircle"/>
  </svg>


  <!-- Hover me icon -->
  <span>:hover clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0 round 50%)</span>
  <svg class="icon">
    <style>
      .iconTransform {
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: clip-path .18s ease-out; 
        clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0 round 15px);
      }

      .iconTransform:hover {
        clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0 round 50%);
      }
    </style>
    <use class="iconTransform" href="#icon"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

#### More info:

- [Animating with Clip-Path](https://css-tricks.com/animating-with-clip-path/)